# Problem with writing the first line to a CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I'm using a thread to run one function of my code, here's a snippet:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    for addresses in ipa_str_s:
        futures.append(executor.submit(checking_connection, ip_address=addresses))
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        save_result = (future.result())
        saving_statistics(save_result, saving)
```

the variable `ipa_str_s` has a list of IP addresses.

the `saving_statistics` function, which waits for each call of the `checking_connection` function to give me the opportunity to `save the result`.

Called function `saving_statistics`:

```
def saving_statistics(save_result, saving):
    with open(saving, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        csv_writer.writerow(['IP-address', 'Packets_transmitted', 'Packets_received'])
        csv_writer.writerow(save_result)
```

if specify the mode `a`, then get this result:

```
IP-address;Packets_transmitted;Packets_received
192.168.1.1;3;3
IP-address;Packets_transmitted;Packets_received;
192.168.1.2;3;0
IP-address;Packets_transmitted;Packets_received;
192.168.1.3;3;0
```

if specify the mode `w`, then get this result:

```
IP-address;Packets_transmitted;Packets_received
192.168.1.3;3;0
```

Could you tell me please, how can I come to the normal content of a file like this:

```
IP-address;Packets_transmitted;Packets_received
192.168.1.1;3;3
192.168.1.2;3;0
192.168.1.3;3;0
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your overall process is as simple as making a number of async network connections, then collecting the results into a CSV file, and this process probably runs in a *reasonable* amount of time, and there won't be restarts. If so, don't append.

Like Loydms stated, just open then write then close:

```py
import csv
import random
import time

import concurrent.futures


def checking_connection(addr):
    sleep_ms = random.randrange(50, 100) / 1000
    time.sleep(sleep_ms)

    pckts_in = random.randrange(500, 1000)
    pckts_out = random.randrange(500, 1000)

    return addr, pckts_in, pckts_out, sleep_ms


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    for address in [f"192.168.1.{x}" for x in range(256)]:
        futures.append(executor.submit(checking_connection, address))


with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(["IP_address", "Packets_transmitted", "Packets_received", "Sleep"])
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        writer.writerow(future.result())
```

When I run that code, I get a new CSV every time, with a header and 256 rows of fake IP stats in about 1.8s:

```
| IP_address    | Packets_transmitted | Packets_received | Sleep |
|---------------|---------------------|------------------|-------|
| 192.168.1.94  | 879                 | 933              | 0.063 |
| 192.168.1.245 | 846                 | 577              | 0.079 |
| 192.168.1.144 | 555                 | 656              | 0.099 |
| 192.168.1.127 | 659                 | 936              | 0.06  |
| 192.168.1.43  | 706                 | 740              | 0.091 |
...
```

If your process takes an unreasonable amount of time, or there are restarts, then either pick a logging approach or use Python's SQLite3 module to create a small DB and do inserts.

From either a log file or the DB you can create the CSV when it's ultimately needed.

Comment: That's great! and how I didn't think about it. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexRebell, Ah, I think a lot of us get wrapped up in our ideas and ways. I know I've benefited so many times from just another pair of eyes and the question, "why?".

Comment: can I ask you to tell me about the progress bar for `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`? is there any way to track the execution of this thread? I'm sorry, I'm not creating a new question, I think you will solve this issue with ease.

Comment: I know nothing of ThreadPoolExecutor. I’d definitely check to see if that question has already been asked, and ask a new one if not.

Answer (score 2):

Your function writes the first line (IP-address;Packets_transmitted;Packets_recieved) every time the function saving_statistics gets called.

I see three solutions:

1. Open the file elsewhere and write the first line, then call the function as needed. Close the file when the program terminates.
2. Have a variable that is True when the function is first called, and then have it changed to false. Use this to determine whether or not to print the header line
3. Save the ip addresses in a list object, and write all of them when the program terminates.

Depending on how long you want it to run changes the best option. If you plan for it to run a while, I would do 1 and have a file.close() at the end of your main(), or however you are running this. If it is a short number of items, 3 may be the easiest. 2 will result in the least amount of code change.

Comment: I'd go for #1: when "main" starts look for your CSV and if it doesn't exist create it and write the header. From then on anything else can just simply open-for-append and write to it.

Comment: @ZachYoung, I chose the 1st option.  I would like to know if this is included in the `best practices`?

Comment: @AlexRebell, no, I don't think appending to a CSV is a good practice, in general. I'm also having a hard time reasoning about why your code is doing what's it doing, so I might be missing something. I've put down my best guess as to what your overall need is, and the approach I'd take.